# pg_restore: error: did not find magic string in file header

Tags: pg-restore

> C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\15\bin\pg_restore.exe --verbose --host=localhost --port=5434 --username=postgres --clean --no-owner --create --format=c --dbname=PsiDB_New C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\DB_Backup\PsiDB_New_2023-23-06_ 1-01-37.sql
> Task 'PostgreSQL restore' started at Fri Jun 23 18:01:17 CEST 2023
> pg_restore: error: did not find magic string in file header
>
> Task 'PostgreSQL restore' finished at Fri Jun 23 18:01:17 CEST 2023

Before, it worked fine using Custom to restore backups. Now, all of sudden, I am getting this. How can I fix this?

Tried restoring the backup